# Authorizing BitBucket API from Console app

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, console-application, bitbucket-api

I'm building a [Symfony Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) script (PHP).

Is it possible to authorize BitBucket API (oAuth) from a command-line, console-based app (i.e., without browser)?

Or put another way -- does BitBucket allow 2-legged oAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of [this oAuth library](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-bitbucket) to get the access token and [guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to form the requests.  Super simple.  I am using the header method `Authorization: Bearer {access_token}` as documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-238027431.html#OAuthonBitbucket-Makingrequests).